# ASP.net Event Calendar Display Date Range

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar, date-range

I have a calender which highlights the selected date from the database. It currently highlights the start date only...I would like it to highlight the range of dates (start date - send date)

My current code as follows:

```
Function GetCurrentMonthData(ByVal startdate As DateTime, _
                              ByVal enddate As DateTime) As DataSet
    Dim dsMonth As New DataSet
    Dim cs1 As ConnectionStringSettings
    cs1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString1")
    Dim connString As String = cs1.ConnectionString
    Dim dbConnection As New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT holidaydate FROM HolidayRequests WHERE HolidayDate >= @startDate AND HolidayDate < @endDate"

    Dim dbCommand As New SqlCommand(query, dbConnection)
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@startdate", startdate))
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@enddate", enddate))

    Dim sqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand)
    Try
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsMonth)
    Catch
    End Try
    Return dsMonth
End Function

Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) _
        Handles Calendar1.DayRender
    Dim nextDate As DateTime
    If Not dsHolidays Is Nothing Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In dsHolidays.Tables(0).Rows
            nextDate = CType(dr("holidaydate"), DateTime)
            If nextDate = e.Day.Date Then
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I think the query and where statement used is not pulling through the correct information but not entirely sure where or how to correct it ...

Comment: The dates you retrieve from the database are of type DATE? (the db field type is Date or DateTime?)

Comment: Ok, good. Could you also check if `dsHolidays` is set before the `DayRender` events are handled?

Comment: yes dsholidays is at the very top of the class

Comment: Ok, then, add a breakpoint in the `DayRender` method and check if the execution goes to the line `e.Cell.BackColor = ...`

Comment: It skips the e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink

Comment: Ok, but how far does it go? Does the dataset have rows? Are all holidays different from the current date? Put the breakpoint in the begining of the handler and go step by step to see what is actually happening.

Comment: It goes to the  nextDate = CType(dr("holidaydate"), DateTime) and seems to show the nextdate as 02/012/2012 (which is correct) and then the Date as 01/30/11

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7733/discussion-between-mazzucci-and-user1055487)

Answer (score 0):

The DayRender Sub needed to be changed as follows:

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) _
        Handles Calendar1.DayRender
    Dim nextDate As DateTime
    Dim StartDate As DateTime
    Dim Enddate As DateTime
    Dim username As String

    If Not dsHolidays Is Nothing Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In dsHolidays.Tables(0).Rows
            StartDate = CType(dr("StartDate"), DateTime)
            Enddate = CType(dr("EndDate"), DateTime)
            nextDate = CType(dr("startdate"), DateTime)
            username = CType(dr("username"), String)

            If e.Day.Date >= StartDate And e.Day.Date <= Enddate Then


                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```